# Does the integral $ \int \frac{\sin (x)}{x} \ dx $ exist?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to find the integral,

$$ \int \frac{\sin (9 + 3 {\sqrt[3] {\ x} )}} {\sqrt[3]{\ x^2}} \ dx.$$

I have used a substitution with $u = {(9 + 3 {\sqrt[3] {\ x} )}}$ and $du = dx/\sqrt[3]{\ x^2}$ and that lead me to:

$$ \int \frac{\sin x}{x}\  dx.$$

I want to simplify this further, but am unsure how to do proceed.  Does this integral exist?

Comment: Just asking whether it converges or what?

Comment: $\int \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$ is a well-known integral. You should be able to find a lot about it, including convergence, via a Google search.

Comment: You will not be able to express the antiderivative as some finite expression involving elementary functions.

Comment: The integrand is called $\operatorname{sinc}$.

Comment: An antiderivative definitely exists on certain domains. Could you specify a domain on which the antiderivative it supposed to be defined, and what kind of answer you are looking for? An antiderivative can be somewhat dissapointing in this kind of problem if you dont have something specific you are looking for. For example, if you are looking on some interval $[a,b]$, with $0<a<b$, then $\int_a^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt$ is an antiderivative, but is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: As that function is continous everywhere (except for a removable discontinuity at $\;x=0\;$), it has a primitive function on any closed, finite interval...at least. Now, to be able to express that primitive as a finite chain of elementary functions is way another thing...

Comment: The given substitution actually converts your integral to$$\int\sin u\mathrm du=-\cos u+C=-\cos(9+3x^{1/3})+C.$$

Comment: @J.G. Maybe you should write that as an answer.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I originally limited it to a comment because it addresses the original integral but not the question that emerged regarding $\int\frac{\sin u}{u}\mathrm du$. I've decided in light of your recommendation that it's best to leave an answer (which I now have), as long as it spells out which part-question it addresses. Thanks for the push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At @A-LevelStudent's suggestion, I'm noting in this answer that, quite separate from the discussion the OP encouraged (and which other answers provided) of $\int\frac{\sin u}{u}\mathrm du$, the given substitution instead writes the original integral as$$\int\sin u\mathrm du=-\cos u+C=-\cos(9+3\sqrt[3]{x})+C.$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you are dealing with real functions here, though it is possible to extend this treatment to the complex domain.  The definite integral of the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) is the [sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral):

$$\text{Si}(x) = \int \limits_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t} \ dt
\quad \quad \quad \text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

This cannot be written as a finite set of operations on elementary functions, so you are probably stuck with the integral representation, or other representations that are equally complicated.  You can find expansions for the sine integral in [Harris (2000)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168927499000318), but this is fairly complicated.  You can also find some results showing uniform convergence of generalised sine integrals in [Móricz (2009)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X09000158).

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\text{Si}(x)+\text{constant}$$
Si$(x)$ is a known function. One can find its properties in the handbooks of standard functions. For example, see :

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral

This is just like $\int \frac{1}{x}dx$ :

As you are familiar with the function $\ln(x)$ you know that $\int \frac{1}{x}dx=\ln(x)+\text{constant}$.

When you will be familiar with the function Si$(x)$ you will know that $\int \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\text{Si}(x)+\text{constant}$.

That may come as a surprise to people who are not familiar with special functions. A discussion about the use of special functions (pp.18-36) : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales
. The function Si$(x)$ is mentioned in section 4 page 24 and in table 4 page 32 among some special functions on similar kind.